# How to know insert date for a row in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, date, insert

Is there any way to find insert date for a row in mysql database without adding a date column...?

I have some records of clients query in mysql database I forgot to add date column to track insert date and time. I need to know when row is inserted in table.

Comment: There is no information like this available. Best of luck.

Comment: The best you can do is to start checking your backups to see when the data appeared.

Answer (score 7):

MySQL does not store timestamps per rows. If you did not save it yourself (e.g., by adding a timestamp column to your table and populating it with a trigger), there's no way to retrieve this information from the database.